# JQuery post does not work correctly

Tags: jquery

I am going crazy, I don't know why but my very simple Jquery post does not work correctly.
I have index.php and temp.php as below. I am still getting "NOT RETURNED OK", don't know why because the data returns "ok" if I alert it before the if condition.

index.php:

```
<? session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="windows-1250">

<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-   ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js">              </script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

 <script>

function do_post(item)
{     
  $.post("temp.php", {par:item}, function(data,status){
  //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  if(data=="ok")
  {
   alert('RETURNED OK');
   //location.reload();
  }
  else
  {
   alert('NOT RETURNED OK');
  }
 });
}

</script>

<body>
<a href="#" onclick="do_post('whatever');">click</a>
</body>
</html>

temp.php:
<? echo "ok"; ?>
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: `data` may contain invisible characters.

Comment: Well he stated if he runs alert(data) he gets back 'ok'.

Comment: @EvanMulawski may well be right. Try this: before your if(data) statement, add 'console.log(typeof data, data.length)' and tell us what the console returns.

Comment: you can also try using 'debbuger;' before if condition and see what data has been returned

Answer (score 0):

I suggest either using JSON in your response with the proper response header content type, or explicitly tell jQuery .post what you expect back:

```
$.post("temp.php", {par:item}, function(){}, 'text');
```

If you're simply echo'ing in your php script, you arent specifying a content type in your header, which may not be parsed by jQuery correctly as it has to take a guess of what it's working with. Also look for line breaks.

Comment: Thank you guys, you are right, there are carriage return and new line chars. It should have occured to me :-(. I don't know where it comes from (probably different IDE and webftp). But I used trim function and it works now :) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I have run the code on my localhost and it's working fine. However, the php opening tags were not interpreted by my server and i had to add the word php to them